# SQL Dynamic Lead

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need a way to use the offset for the `LEAD` function SQL dynamically. My data is structured as follows:

[image: Sample Data]

What I am trying to accomplish is to retrieve the value of `D365Object` from the next row with the same `GMLD` like this:

[image: Results I Want]

My query for the sample file is as follows:

```
SELECT [D365ODept],[D365OObject],[GMLDA]
FROM [JDE].[F0901]
WHERE isnumeric([D365OObject]) = 1  
GROUP BY [D365ODept],[D365OObject],[GMLDA]
ORDER BY [D365ODept],[D365OObject],[GMLDA]
```

Comment: What's the issue with using `LEAD(D365Object) OVER (PARTITION BY GMLD ORDER BY D365Object)`? It's not dynamic as far as I understand your question, you just need to partition by GMLD, don't you?

Comment: If I wrote a really nice but long solution query, took a screenshot of it, and added that image as an answer, would you be annoyed about the unnecessary transcription effort? Please don't use images of data, just copy/paste some data into the question and format it using the `{}` button in the toolbar. ps: You can use https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to create ascii tables.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was looking for a way to insert tables in this site, but could not find a way to do so. To answer your question, I would not have minded the transcription effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the advice from @ZLK in the comments...

```
CREATE TABLE F0901  
(
  D365ODept VARCHAR(50),
  D365OObject VARCHAR(10),
  GMLDA INT,
);

INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01100', '6');
INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01100', '7');
INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01200', '5');
INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01210', '6');
INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01210', '7');
INSERT INTO F0901 (D365ODept, D365OObject, GMLDA) VALUES ('00', '01250', '6');

SELECT f.D365ODept
      ,f.D365OObject
      ,f.GMLDA
      ,LEAD(f.D365OObject) OVER (PARTITION BY f.GMLDA ORDER BY f.D365OObject) as next_D365OObject
  FROM F0901 f;
```

If you choose to include code that builds and loads a schema in your question as opposed to images, a larger number of folks will be interested in answering.

Click here to learn [how to format code blocks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I don't know if you can answer this, but if I have another question regarding the same set of data and it is of similar nature, should I create another question this site or should I ask the question here? The question is more challenging, but is almost the same, with a twist.

Comment: @JoelVega you are welcome. It depends. This article can help you decide: [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It probably merits a new question.